# Python pyQt MVC- Passing Objects To The Model Class

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt

1. How is it that `self.model = MyTableModel(self, [User('Mary',
   '12345'), User('John', 'qwerty')], ['name', 'password'])` can pass
   object instance `User('Mary', '12345')` to `MyTableModel()` when I don't
   see  `def __init__(self, parent, rows, columns)` set up to take  it? 
   From what I know, rows and columns are arguments to take info from
   the widget object and not a outside non widget object.
2. What does the last part `['name', 'password']` do when given to
   MyTableModel()?
3. Actually, I want just one instance of User() and have the model
   class update User() object instance if the human changes the
   lineEdit widget. since "mary" and "12345" in self.model =
   MyTableModel(self, [User('Mary', '12345')] are hardcoded values, how
   do I use the values of the lineEdit widgets instead in
   User(parameter, parameter)?

   ```
   from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
   import sys

   class User():
       def __init__(self, name, password):
           self.name = name
           self.password = password


   class MyTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

       def __init__(self, parent, rows, columns):
           super().__init__(parent)
           self.rows = rows
           self.columns = columns

       def columnCount(self, index):
           return len(self.columns)

       def rowCount(self, index):
           return len(self.rows)

       def data(self, index, role):
           if index.isValid():
               if (role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole) or (role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
                   attr_name = self.columns[index.column()]
                   row = self.rows[index.row()]
                   return getattr(row, attr_name)

       def flags(self, index):
           if not index.isValid():
               return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
           else:
               return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

       def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
           if index.isValid() and role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
               attr_name = self.columns[index.column()]
               row = self.rows[index.row()]
               setattr(row, attr_name, value)


   class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
       def __init__(self):
           super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
           self.setLayout(QtGui.QFormLayout(self))
           self.user_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
           self.password_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
           self.mapper = QtGui.QDataWidgetMapper(self)
           self.model = MyTableModel(self, [User('Mary', '12345'), User('John', 'qwerty')], ['name', 'password'])
           self.mapper.setModel(self.model)
           self.mapper.addMapping(self.user_edit, 0)
           self.mapper.addMapping(self.password_edit, 1)
           self.mapper.toFirst()

           self.layout().addRow("User name:", self.user_edit)
           self.layout().addRow("Password:", self.password_edit)

           self.btnPrevious = QtGui.QPushButton("Previous", self)
           self.btnNext = QtGui.QPushButton("Next",self)
           self.layout().addWidget(self.btnPrevious)
           self.layout().addWidget(self.btnNext)

           self.btnPrevious.clicked.connect(self.mapper.toPrevious)
           self.btnNext.clicked.connect(self.mapper.toNext)

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
       win = MyWindow()
       win.show()
       app.exec_()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How is it that `self.model = MyTableModel(self, [User('Mary',
>      '12345'), User('John', 'qwerty')], ['name', 'password'])` can pass
>      object instance `User('Mary', '12345')` to `MyTableModel()` when I don't
>      see  `def __init__(self, parent, rows, columns)` set up to take  it? 
>      From what I know, rows and columns are arguments to take info from
>      the widget object and not a outside non widget object.

The parameter do not stand here for rows and columns in the Qt-MVC-sense. Rather, rows should be a list of objects and columns a list of strings denoting the attributes of the passed objects (in the row argument) that should be exhibited by the model instance.

> 1. What does the last part `['name', 'password']` do when given to
>      MyTableModel()?

The MyTableModel uses it to know which attributes of the objects should be used for display.

> 1. Actually, I want just one instance of User() and have the model
>      class update User() object instance if the human changes the
>      lineEdit widget. since "mary" and "12345" in self.model =
>      MyTableModel(self, [User('Mary', '12345')] are hardcoded values, how
>      do I use the values of the lineEdit widgets instead in
>      User(parameter, parameter)?

As your model implements the `setData` protocol properly and returns `ItemIsEditable` for all items in the model the user can already change the values *inside the model* (or a view using that model). You do not need additional inputs or change GUIs to accomplish that.

(If you just wanted to know how to get the current text contents of a QLineEdit, that's the `text()` method)